# Transfer ownership of in app purchases to new email address?

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

I made some in-app purchases a year ago with email address foo@foo.com.

I have since changed my email address to new@new.com. Is there any way that I can transfer my purchases from my old email address to my new email address in the Google Play app?

Comment: You can try asking the developer if it is a few apps .

Answer (score 1):

No there is no official way to transfer purchases from one account to another. You could contact the Google Services to maybe figure out a way if you had a good reason which you could explain.

There is a Reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/2r57b5/is_there_still_no_way_to_transfer_all_google_play/) regarding this topic if that is any help.

Comment: Consider quoting the " meat (Reasons)", from the Reddit link in your answer. That way your answer well gain more credibility and visibility

Comment: With google expiring google accounts that haven't been used for a while, this means that you can lose content your purchased.

How is it legal for google to "sell" you a movie, but then close your account without giving you the ability to either transfer to another account or reimburse you?

Given that you have "bought" the rights to watch that movie, can you legally download an illegal copy and watch it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way Google can transfer in-app purchases from one account to another. This is actually up to the application developer to help resolve your issue. I highly recommend contacting the developer to either (1) transfer your content from the old email address to the new one or (2) getting a refund for all those purchases.